# TypeScript return object after firebase login

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, types, ionic2

i have the following code

```
login = (email: string, senha: string): { nome: string, genero: string, foto: string;} => {
    this.fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, senha).then(res => {
        firebase.database().ref('Usuarios/' + res.uid).once('value', snapshot => {
            return {
                nome: snapshot.val().nome,
                genero: snapshot.val().genero,
                foto: snapshot.val().avatar
            };
        });
    });
}
```

and i need it to return a object after i login in firebase and then get my info, but it throws an error that i must return something if the function type is not 'void' or 'any', but i'm returning a object as specified.

What can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong the concept of async and promises.
There are a few options to solve it.

1 - You can return the promise an let the caller resolve it.

```
login = (email: string, senha: string): Promise<{nome: string, genero: string, foto: string}> => {
    return new Promise<{nome: string, genero: string, foto: string}>((resolver, rejeitar) => {
        this.fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, senha).then(res => {
            firebase.database().ref('Usuarios/' + res.uid).once('value', snapshot => {
                resolver({
                    nome: snapshot.val().nome,
                    genero: snapshot.val().genero,
                    foto: snapshot.val().avatar
                });
            });
        });
    });
}
```

2 - You can send an callback in the login function and execute it when the promise is executed

```
login = (email: string, senha: string, loginCallback: (nome: string, genero: string, foto: string) => any) => {
    this.fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, senha).then(res => {
        firebase.database().ref('Usuarios/' + res.uid).once('value', snapshot => {
            loginCallback({
                nome: snapshot.val().nome,
                genero: snapshot.val().genero,
                foto: snapshot.val().avatar
            });
        });
    });
}
```

**Edit:** I checked the Firebase Documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once). There is a second error too.

```
firebase.database().ref('Usuarios/' + res.uid).once('value', snapshot => {
```

should be:

```
firebase.database().ref('Usuarios/' + res.uid).once('value').then(snapshot => {
```

Comment: will try your solution and inform you soon if this worked. Handling promisses breaks my app on login, but i think it's only firebase promisses, other component promisses don't break it (don't know why, but there's a lot of github issues about this).

Comment: It's because you are using like Sync Programing. When using Async, you have to use callbacks to receive the answer of an operation.
Promises == Async

Comment: There is no way to runaway from promises. You have to embrace then haha. I went through the same!

Comment: Cara agora que vi que vc é BR hahaha MUITO OBRIGADO resolveu 2 problemas em uma pedrada so. Eu tava tratando as promessas, mas usando componente do Ionic nas promessas do firebase quebrava meu app, fazendo essa promessa por fora não quebra nada e deixou o login mais rapido. Valeu mesmo cara

Comment: At the beginning it's really different to use promisses. But with time, you get used. You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Your inner function within `once` returns an object. Not the function assigned to login. The outermost function should return a promise.

Try:

```
login = (email: string, senha: string): Promise<any> => {
   //return here as well
   return this.fireAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, senha).then(res => {
       //return the database call 
      return firebase.database().ref('Usuarios/' + res.uid).once('value', snapshot => {
            return {
                nome: snapshot.val().nome,
                genero: snapshot.val().genero,
                foto: snapshot.val().avatar
            };
        });
    });
}
```